# Input from a file and strip

Tags: python, strip

I'm trying to execute a code where it reads the input (IP) from a file and then executes a show command for each device. I'm trying to use `rstrip` so that `\n` is removed before connection handler but getting error:

```
   a_device = a_device.rstrip()
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

```py
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
Device_IP =  open(r'C:\ATT_Devices.txt','r')
List1 = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'host':   'Device_IP',
    'username': 'USERNAME',
    'password': 'PASSWORD',
 }
all_devices = [List1]
for a_device in all_devices:
    a_device = a_device.rstrip() # error thrown here
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**a_device)
    output = net_connect.send_command("show ip bgp summary")

    print(output)
```

Comment: `List1` is a dictionary. `all_devices` is a list of dictionaries. `a_device` is a dictionary. So what did you *expect* from `a_device.rstrip()`? Also why open the file, nothing seems to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jon. I know this code(leaving rstrip) works when i mention IP address directly in host of list1. Intention here is to create a code where i can input multiple IP address through a notepad and execute show ip bgp summary. I was thinking a \n after each line in the notepad could be cause(faced earlier) so tried to strip

Comment: Additionally i will adding more dictionaries to all_devices.

Answer (score 0):

all_devices = [List1] --> Does not convert dictionary into list.
Instead try using all_devices = list(List1) --> for converting dict. into list.

```
all_devices = list(List1)
for a_device in all_devices:
    a_device = a_device.rstrip()
    print(a_device)
```